Ломанные линии при соединении точек мультимаршрута на Яндекс картах

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли у Яндекс карт какие-то инструменты, позволяющие прокладывать дорогу между точками мультимаршрута не прямой линией, а так, чтобы путь пролегал непосредственно по дороге? У меня есть маршрут из нескольких точек и я буду добавлять еще один маркер движения автобуса. Получая данные в реальном времени, маркер автобуса будет двигаться на карте именно по дороге и станет выходить за пределы линии между точками мультимаршрута, что неприемлемо.
Поддерживается ли, в целом, построение мультимаршрута не ломаной линией, а как-либо еще?
Проект на React, используется версия api 2.1

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Отображение маршрута по дорогам возможно. В нашей песочнице есть пример настройки мультимаршрута. Также можете ознакомиться с разделом документации Настройка внешнего вида маршрута.
